# MongoDB reference not creating using / MERN Stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am working on my final year project, new to MERN stack facing issue in creating reference in mongoDB documents.
using two models and one controller to save data in different documents, at the same time how can i save student_id as a ref in parentdata document.

AdmissionController.js

```
  const newStudent = new studentModel({
          s_fname,
          s_lname,
          gender,
          age
     })
     const ParentData = new parentModel({
           fatherName,
           father_cnic, 
           FatherDesignation, 
           fatherMobile,
           motherName    
     })
     newStudent.save()
     ParentData.save()
```

in parentModel

```
 student_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'student'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Make sure if you are exporting **Student** or **student** from student model

```
student_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Student",
    },
```

Also can you share the complete code of both parent and student models.